# Вывод Б-дерева (B-Tree) в TreeView

Tags: delphi, pascal

может кто нибудь подсказать по Б-деревьям? Но не по самому алгоритму, а по выводу, есть код который вывод в консоль обычного паскаля, а надо в компонент TreeView. Вот последовательность чисел для заполнения дерева: 5 10 30 11 19
Как выглядит это дерево наглядно:

[image: Вот как выглядит дерево наглядно]

Вот исходный код для вывод в консоль Паскаля:

```
procedure printtree(p:ref; l:integer);
  var i:integer;
  begin
   if p <> nil then
   with p^ do
   begin
    for i:= 1 to l do write('. ');
    for i:=1 to m do
    write(e[i].key,' ');
    writeln;
    printtree(p0,l+1);
    for i:=1 to m do printtree(e[i].p,l+1);
   end;
end;
```

Сам вывод:

[image: Сам вывод]

Как я пытался сделать вывод в delphi используя компонент TreeView:

```
procedure printtree(p:ref; l:integer);
var
i:integer;
begin
  if p <> nil then
  with p^ do
   begin
    for i:=1 to m do
      RootNode:=Form1.TreeView1.Items.Add(p,IntToStr(e[i].key));
    printtree(p0,l+1);
    for i:=1 to m do
      printtree(e[i].p,l+1);
   end;
end;
```

Выходит в одну(вертикальную) строку, не могу понять как сделать потомков для узла:

```
11
5
10
19
30
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример рекурсивного заполнения `Treeview`.

Вместо цикла, заданного арифметикой, у Вас будет должно запрашиваться количество детей узла, либо выполняться проход по связанному списку детей.

Однако в Treeview не показать нормальным образом **отношение порядка** узлов и родителя.

```
procedure TVFill(Node: TTreeNode; Data: Integer);
var
  tn: TTreeNode;
  i: integer;
begin
  if Data > 100 then
    Exit;
  tn := TreeView1.Items.AddChild(Node, Data.ToString);
  for i := 1 to 3 do
    TVFill(tn, 3 * Data + i);
end;

begin
  TVFill(nil, 0);
```